# How to cancel the pagenumber of content page?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, page-numbering

I am trying to cancel the pagenumber in content pages. I haved tried command `\thispagestyle{empty}`,but it didn't work! Another way I have tried is as following, but there is always a '2' showing on the first content page,which annoys me so much! Could anyone help me with this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}  
\title{Functional Analysis}
\author{333}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{plain} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}      
\section{BalaBalaBala}      
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\section{BalaBalaBala}  
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}   
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\subsection{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\chapter{BalaBalaBala}
\section{BalaBalaBala}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the `tocloft` package and issue the directive `\tocloftpagestyle{empty}` in the preamble.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}  
\frontmatter
\title{Functional Analysis}
\author{333}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{BalaBalaBala}  
\section{BalaBalaBala} 
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}
```

in the preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\title{Functional Analysis}
\author{333}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]